# Best way to keep data in an object updated based on some logic?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I am creating an app where an 'Episode' object has a 'air_time' and 'air_status' field.

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    air_time = models.DateTimeField()
    air_status = models.TextField(default="UPCOMING")
    # air_status can contain UPCOMING, LIVE or VOD in the original code
```

I want to keep the 'air_status' field updated depending on the 'air_time' field.
Where in the application should I process and update the 'air_status' field? I was thinking of two options:

1. Upon request of the object in a view the **view** will update the 'air_status' field. Disadvantage is that if the object is never loaded the field 'air_status' is not updated in the database.
2. Make a check in some way in the model file to update 'air_status' when the current time is equal to 'air_time'.

I know how to do option 1 but no idea on 2. What is the best solution? Thanks!

Comment: Don't store logic in a database, query it's data instead

Comment: By that do you mean removing the 'air_status' field and just figuring it out in the view to pass it on to the template? The problem with that is that I then can't make three categories 'VOD', 'LIVE', and 'UPCOMING' on all objects.

Comment: Yea. By the sound of it the status can be determined based off the air_time (maybe needs a duration too)

Comment: So if I ever want to get all the episodes in a paginator which have been aired already, I need to do something like this (?) : Episode.objects.all.filter(air_time__lt=datetime.datetime.now()). I was afraid that'd be resource intensive but I might just choose this option then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this dynamically without storing anything in the database. There are two ways of doing this.

#### Model property

The easiest way is to just add a property to your model. The downside is that you can't query by this field.

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    air_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def air_status(self):
        if self.air_time < now():
            return 'UPCOMNG'
        elif self.air_time >= now() and self.end_time < now():
            return 'LIVE'
        else:
            return 'VOD'
```

Now you can easily access it like any other property on the object: `episode.duration`.

#### [Custom Queryset/Manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers)

If you have to query by this field, you can also add a custom manager to your model.

```
class EpisodeManager(models.Manager):
    def upcoming(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(air_time__lt=now())

    def live(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(
            air_time__gte=now(),
            end_time__lt=now()
        )

    def vod(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(
            end_time__lte=now()
        )

class Episode(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = EpisodeManager()
```

Now you can ask for episodes of a certain type: `Episode.objects.vod()` for example.

Of course you can keep extending this and implement a [custom queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager) so you can take any arbitrary `Episode` model query and filter it like `Episode.objects.filter(title='Game of Thrones').live()`.

Comment: Wow! Amazing answer, I haven't seen the Managers used yet but they seem really cool. I will implement both methods. One last question: based on .air_status I want to change the css/html for a certain element on the page. I am correct this logic should be in the template itself, so something like this: {% if episode.air_status == 'LIVE' %} live css/html header (red color) {%  else } not live css/html header (blue color) {% endif % }. Is this the preferred way to do something like this?

Comment: I would implement it as a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) so you don't have to keep repeating yourself. Then you can just use it like this: `episode.status|status_color`. If you want more than just colors, implement properties on the model for all three statuses: `episode.is_live`, `episode.is_upcoming` and `episode.is_vod` and do `{% if episode.is_live %}...{% endif %}`. Remember the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

Comment: I indeed want some custom html for each status. I'll add those three properties as functions too to the model. Just to make sure: the custom HTML should never be in the model right but instead in the template right? {% if episode.is_live %}<h1>LIVE</h2>{% endif %}{% if episode.is_vod %}<p>Watch VOD!{% endif %}{% if episode.is_upcoming %}<h2>Upcoming!</h2>{% endif %}. Thanks so much for helping out o//.